# Show data in inputbox from 1 object and save it in using another object

Tags: angularjs

I'm clicking a table row to edit the fields in a modal. The modal must have 2 functionalities (Add or Edit) depending on the GET request data like below.

```
$scope.editInterview = function(id) {
    $http.get('/api/getinterview/' + id).then(function(response) {
        editedObject = response.data.item
}
```

HTML

```
    <label ng-if="editedObject.email">{{editedObject.email}}</label>
    <label ng-if="!editedObject.email">Email</label>

    <input ng-model="newObject.email" />
```

[image]

I am able to display the object in the `labels`, but that's not much help, because the data needs to be shown in the input boxes to be Edited and Saved.

**How can i show the data from `editedObject.email` in the input, so i can save it using `newObject.email`?**

I tried `ng-init="editedObject.email"`, but it doesn't work. Is there some other `ng-something` that does this or i should be doing it in another way?

---

**Update:**

Edit and Update Methods, both are in the mainController.

```
$scope.editInterview = function(id) {
    $http.get('/api/getinterview/' + id).then(function(response) {
        editedObject = response.data.item
    })
}

//Controller for the Modal
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, editedObject) {

    $scope.editedObject = editedObject

    $scope.submitObject = function(newObject) {
        $http.post('/api/interview', newObject)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a deep copy from `editObject.email` to `newObject.email`. This could be done this way in controller after `editOject.email` has a value assigned.

```
$scope.newObject.email = angular.copy($scope.editObject.email);
```

Comment: I updated the question with the Edit Button function  `editInterview `, and the function that the Modal is using. The `editedObject` is being assigned on the `GET` request,  but the `newObject` is comming from the view. How can i di this if the `newObject` is only set in the view?

Comment: If I get it right you want to set the `$scope.newObject.email` which is assigned as model in the `input` field to be equal to the `$scope.editObject.email`. If this is the purpose then the way to go is the one I present on my **Updated** answer. If not you have to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Yes the $scope! This got me so twisted for half a day, that i started having bad thoughts xD  I didn't know about `angular.copy`, need to do some more reading about this. Thank you so moch for the help Korte!